# Vaadin NPE in ServerRpcHandler

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, vaadin

This week I started using Vaadin and has made a big impression on me ever since. However, I came accross a problem which I am not able to resolve. Basically I made a web application where I display Contacts (stored in my database) and display them in a Table.

Since I am using Hibernate, I start off with the following lines of code:

```
    JPAContainer<Contact>contactContainer = new JPAContainer<Contact>(Contact.class);
    CachingMutableLocalEntityProvider<Contact> entityProvider = new CachingMutableLocalEntityProvider<Contact>(Contact.class, em);
    contactContainer.setEntityProvider(entityProvider);

    contactsList = new ContactsList(contactContainer);
```

As you can see, I pass my container to a class called ContactsList where the table etc. is built:

```
    table = new Table();
    table.setWidth(100, Unit.PERCENTAGE);
    table.addStyleName(ValoTheme.TABLE_BORDERLESS);
    table.addStyleName(ValoTheme.TABLE_COMPACT);
    table.setSelectable(true);
    table.setColumnCollapsingAllowed(true);

    if(container != null)
    {
        table.setContainerDataSource(this.container);
        table.setSortAscending(true);
        table.setVisibleColumns("firstName", "lastName", "telephoneNr", "gsmNr", "creationDate");
        table.setColumnHeaders(SpringUtil.getMessage("label.contacts_firstname", null), 
                                SpringUtil.getMessage("label.contacts_lastname", null), 
                                SpringUtil.getMessage("label.contacts_telephone_nr", null), 
                                SpringUtil.getMessage("label.contacts_gsm_nr", null),
                                SpringUtil.getMessage("label.contacts_creationdate", null));
    }

    table.setMultiSelect(true);
    table.setImmediate(true);
```

When I comment out all this code, my application runs perfectly without crashing (ofcourse not showing the contacts table) but when I try and compile this code, while debugging everything works well even after the table has been built but then a NPE is thrown in the class `ServerRpcHandler` on the lines:

```
if (invocation instanceof ServerRpcMethodInvocation) {
    try {
        ServerRpcManager.applyInvocation(connector,
                 (ServerRpcMethodInvocation) invocation);
        } catch (RpcInvocationException e) {
                  manager.handleConnectorRelatedException(connector, e);
        }
} else {
```

The full StackTrace is shown here:

```
    SEVERE: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.vaadin.addon.jpacontainer.provider.LocalEntityProvider.getEntityManager(LocalEntityProvider.java:215)
    at com.vaadin.addon.jpacontainer.provider.LocalEntityProvider.doGetEntityManager(LocalEntityProvider.java:226)
    at com.vaadin.addon.jpacontainer.provider.LocalEntityProvider.doGetEntityCount(LocalEntityProvider.java:510)
    at com.vaadin.addon.jpacontainer.provider.CachingSupport$FilterCacheEntry.getEntityCount(CachingSupport.java:157)
    at com.vaadin.addon.jpacontainer.provider.CachingSupport.getEntityCount(CachingSupport.java:826)
    at com.vaadin.addon.jpacontainer.provider.CachingMutableLocalEntityProvider.getEntityCount(CachingMutableLocalEntityProvider.java:130)
    at com.vaadin.addon.jpacontainer.JPAContainer.size(JPAContainer.java:912)
    at com.vaadin.ui.AbstractSelect.size(AbstractSelect.java:762)
    at com.vaadin.ui.Table.refreshRenderedCells(Table.java:1727)
    at com.vaadin.ui.Table.attach(Table.java:4298)
    at com.vaadin.server.AbstractClientConnector.attach(AbstractClientConnector.java:590)
    at com.vaadin.ui.AbstractComponent.attach(AbstractComponent.java:577)
    at com.vaadin.server.AbstractClientConnector.attach(AbstractClientConnector.java:590)
    at com.vaadin.ui.AbstractComponent.attach(AbstractComponent.java:577)
    at com.vaadin.server.AbstractClientConnector.attach(AbstractClientConnector.java:590)
    at com.vaadin.ui.AbstractComponent.attach(AbstractComponent.java:577)
    at com.vaadin.server.AbstractClientConnector.attach(AbstractClientConnector.java:590)
    at com.vaadin.ui.AbstractComponent.attach(AbstractComponent.java:577)
    at com.vaadin.server.AbstractClientConnector.attach(AbstractClientConnector.java:590)
    at com.vaadin.ui.AbstractComponent.attach(AbstractComponent.java:577)
    at com.vaadin.server.AbstractClientConnector.attach(AbstractClientConnector.java:590)
    at com.vaadin.ui.AbstractComponent.attach(AbstractComponent.java:577)
    at com.vaadin.server.AbstractClientConnector.attach(AbstractClientConnector.java:590)
    at com.vaadin.ui.AbstractComponent.attach(AbstractComponent.java:577)
    at com.vaadin.server.AbstractClientConnector.attach(AbstractClientConnector.java:590)
    at com.vaadin.ui.AbstractComponent.attach(AbstractComponent.java:577)
    at com.vaadin.server.AbstractClientConnector.attach(AbstractClientConnector.java:590)
    at com.vaadin.ui.AbstractComponent.attach(AbstractComponent.java:577)
    at com.vaadin.server.AbstractClientConnector.attach(AbstractClientConnector.java:590)
    at com.vaadin.ui.AbstractComponent.attach(AbstractComponent.java:577)
    at com.vaadin.ui.AbstractComponent.setParent(AbstractComponent.java:484)
    at com.vaadin.ui.AbstractComponentContainer.addComponent(AbstractComponentContainer.java:210)
    at com.vaadin.ui.CssLayout.addComponent(CssLayout.java:120)
    at com.vaadin.navigator.Navigator$ComponentContainerViewDisplay.showView(Navigator.java:191)
    at com.vaadin.navigator.Navigator.navigateTo(Navigator.java:568)
    at com.vaadin.navigator.Navigator.navigateTo(Navigator.java:526)
    at be.cematech.dashboard.ui.DashboardMenu$ValoMenuItemButton$1.buttonClick(DashboardMenu.java:167)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at com.vaadin.event.ListenerMethod.receiveEvent(ListenerMethod.java:508)
    at com.vaadin.event.EventRouter.fireEvent(EventRouter.java:198)
    at com.vaadin.event.EventRouter.fireEvent(EventRouter.java:161)
    at com.vaadin.server.AbstractClientConnector.fireEvent(AbstractClientConnector.java:977)
    at com.vaadin.ui.Button.fireClick(Button.java:387)
    at com.vaadin.ui.Button$1.click(Button.java:55)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at com.vaadin.server.ServerRpcManager.applyInvocation(ServerRpcManager.java:168)
    at com.vaadin.server.ServerRpcManager.applyInvocation(ServerRpcManager.java:118)
    at com.vaadin.server.communication.ServerRpcHandler.handleInvocations(ServerRpcHandler.java:290)
    at com.vaadin.server.communication.ServerRpcHandler.handleRpc(ServerRpcHandler.java:183)
    at com.vaadin.server.communication.UidlRequestHandler.synchronizedHandleRequest(UidlRequestHandler.java:92)
    at com.vaadin.server.SynchronizedRequestHandler.handleRequest(SynchronizedRequestHandler.java:41)
    at com.vaadin.server.VaadinService.handleRequest(VaadinService.java:1404)
    at com.vaadin.server.VaadinServlet.service(VaadinServlet.java:305)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:503)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:421)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1070)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:611)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:316)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

**UPDATE**

What might be useful to know is that I use this ContactList on a different page as well where I have the EXACT same lines of code but where it is able to show the table. Does this have something to do of having two EntityManagers and/or EntityProviders accessing the same data??

**UPDATE2**

```
@PersistenceContext
protected EntityManager em;
```

Comment: Turns out the second time the EntityManager is null ... can someone help me figure out how to fix this issue??

Comment: actually in your code you just pass in your EntityManager. How do you create/retrive it?

Comment: I have it declared on the top of my class file (see UPDATE2)

Comment: Posted an answer, hope it could help ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per Update2 I saw you retrive at runtime your EntityManager with the annotation "@PersistenceContext".
This works out if you are using it in "CDI bean, EJB, Servlet, Servlet Listener, Servlet Filter, or JSF ManagedBean"
( http://tomee.apache.org/examples-trunk/injection-of-entitymanager/README.html )
My guess is that on the "other page" you are in a right context where the annotation works, while in "this" page you are not.
Check this and if it's the case I'd suggest to manually instantiate the EntityManager with for example

```
JPAContainerFactory.make(Contact.class, "PERSISTENCE_UNIT_NAME");
```

if you have/use a persistence.xml file in your project. Otherwise a way would be to custom create an EntityManagerFactory like

```
Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory( "persistence_unit_name", properties ).createEntityManager()
```

where properties is a Map of persistence properties like

```
Map<String, String> properties = new HashMap<String, String>();
properties.put(JDBC_DRIVER, this.jdbcDriver);
properties.put(JDBC_URL, this.url);
properties.put(JDBC_USER, this.username);
properties.put(JDBC_PASSWORD, this.password);

// Configure logging. FINE ensures all SQL is shown
properties.put(LOGGING_LEVEL, "FINE");  
return properties;
```

The perk of EntityManager like this is that you can have it ready whenever you are in your app.
Cheers.